# Sort Range by Date Value in Column

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, datetime

The following code below execute fine but the output of the sort function is a mess.

Intention of code is to sort range of values from B2 to last row of L
According to DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS value

**Code is used to sort a series of files in a folder, so a simple macro recording won't suffice**

```
 Dim Slrow As Long
'Updated last row count to Column B from comment made
Slrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("B2:L" & Slrow).Sort Key1:=Range("B2:L" & Slrow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo


  SortWb.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

**Output of Code**
[image: Output of code]

File Download link available below ->
[Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/maslfi0jan3wyhm/Test.csv?dl=0)

Sorting with Custom Sort

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What is your question (you didn't ask one)? What error do you get? Reading [ask] might help to improve your question. • Probably your `Key1` is wrong (*Specifies the first sort field*) and should be `Range("B2")` to sort by column B. Have a look at [Range.Sort Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-sort-method-excel).

Comment: @peh I thought attaching the picture explains clearly.
Looking at the row number & column B. It isn't exactly sorted according to date & time manner but rather sorted according to value at the front in "DD" position of Date/Time manner

Comment: Did you check your `Key1` as I mentioned?

Comment: Wait, what is the value of `Slrow`? Because looking at your code `Slrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` , you are counting cells in Column A, and in the image, column A is empty, so is not the real last row.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Ohhh right. About that, I removed the the value in column, as is they contain rather sensitive data. But `Slrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` works too

Comment: Please, edit your question adding that information, because i was like OMG! :) so it will be more clear

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I was at the link before asking the question here. `Key1` should only be change if there's another level or sorting criteria to be done right?

Comment: It is in order, as far as Excel is concerned. 6th Feb, 7th Feb, 6th Mar are in date order, then you get to alphabetical text sorting; "30/6" is alphabetically before "31/5". Excel isn't reading/interpreting column B into date data properly. I'd suggest you check your source data and if possible configure the output into YYYY-MM-DD TIME as Excel will always interpret that correctly.

Comment: @CLR I wouldn't be able to change its data source, but would formatting it as YYYY-MM-DD Time be enough before Excel sort it out?

Comment: Yes, even if you ignore dates entirely and sort `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` **alphabetically**, it will become date ordered. Note: `YYYY-M-D hh:mm` (where June is 6, not 06) would still fail though.

Comment: Have you checked.. can you actually manually *(i.e. not using VBA)* sort the table? If the dates are being misinterpreted then you won't be able to sort them the way you want. It's a good test.

Comment: @CLR Yeah. I can sort it using the sort function available. Sorting under Column B(Date/Time) header, sorting on cell value & lastly by order of oldest to newest

Comment: @Tyler then use the Macro Recorder to see what code you get and use this information in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the Key and the range where you apply it, and also the options (looks like your data got headers in row 1). Try something like this:

```
Range("B1:L" & Slrow).Sort Range("B2:B" & Slrow), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes, , False, xlSortColumns, xlPinYin, xlSortNormal
```

Answer (score 1):

- Change the `Key1` to the column you want to sort at eg `Key1:=Range("B1")`.
- use `SortOn:=xlSortOnValues` to make sure it sorts on the values not text (I think this does the trick here).
- make it recognize headers automatically by using `Header:=xlYes` (easier).

This should work:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet 'better specify Worksheets("SheetName")    

With ws.Sort 
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange ws.Range("B1:L" & Slrow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

If it doesn't work your dates are no date values but text and you need to convert them into date values.

Also it might be a good idea *always* to use the ISO date format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` which is the only one that can not be misunderstood by humans and can easily be sorted even as text (eg in file names etc).

Example how it looks sorted with the code above:

[image]

Comment: @Peh I specified the worksheet name, but error pops out on this line `.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal` "Run-Time Error 438" Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Which Excel Version? Try `Add` instead of `Add2`.

Comment: @peh Excel 2016 ProPlus. Add works. However output of code is the same as my code.

Comment: @Tyler Strange I'm on the same Version and `add2` worked. • Then the issue might be that your dates are no dates but text. I tested this with your date format and real date values and it sorted correctly (see my image). So make sure your dates are real dates no text!

Comment: @peh That's odd. I just uploaded a pic using excel available sorting the date/time in order. If it can be done in that manner. VBA should be able to do the same.

Comment: @Tyler If you get it working by doing it manually, then just use the macro recorder to see what code you get. I definitely get it working with the above code.